# How to plot dates in a loop?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

i am trying plot in a loop with matplotlib. I tried to sort the dates before and after .cumsum()... But it always messing up the dates.... Any ideas?

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

count = 0
for channel in all_channel_names:
    df = df_meta.loc[df_meta.index.get_level_values("Channel") == channel].sort_values(by= "publish_date", 
                                                                                       ascending= False)
    df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["publish_date"])
    #display(df.head(20))
    df["cumsum"] = df["views"].cumsum()
    a = df.sort_values(by= "date", ascending= False)
    ax.plot(a["publish_date"], df["cumsum"])
    

plt.ylabel("Number of Videos")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably that you didn't convert `publish_date` column to datetime type.

```py
for channel in all_channel_names:
    df["publish_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["publish_date"])
    # ^^^ convert here

    df = df_meta.loc[df_meta.index.get_level_values("Channel") == channel].sort_values(by= "publish_date", 
                                                                                       ascending= False)
    df["date"] = df["publish_date"]
    # ^^^ If you want to assign to another to column

    #display(df.head(20))
    df["cumsum"] = df["views"].cumsum()
    a = df.sort_values(by= "date", ascending= False)
    ax.plot(a["publish_date"], df["cumsum"])
```

Comment: thx @Ynjxsjmh, unfortunately that doesnt solve the problem...

Comment: @ChrisBee If you could [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors, current output, expected output), as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'm willing to help.